# Circular referencing required for class?

Tags: sql-server

I'm taking a class called Intro To Database Systems.  I'm given a diagram and I need to create tables for it in SQL server.  However, the diagram appears to have circular referencing.  Am I correct in thinking that?  If so, how do I implement it?  Here is the diagram.

[image: Key to A2.png]

As you can see, DNO in EMPLOYEE references DNUMBER in DEPARTMENT, and MGRSSN in DEPARTMENT references SSN in EMPLOYEE.

Here is my code so far, which doesn't work for obvious reasons.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
FNAME   Char(20)    NOT NULL,
MiNIT   Char(1)     NULL,
LNAME   Char(20)    NOT NULL,
SSN     Integer     NOT NULL,
BDATE   Date        NOT NULL,
E_ADDRESS   Char(35)NOT NULL,
SEX     Char(1)     NOT NULL,
SALARY  Money       NOT NULL,
SUPERSSN    Integer NULL,
DNO     Integer     NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY (SSN),
CONSTRAINT DNO_Relationship FOREIGN KEY (DNO)
REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DNUMBER),
CONSTRAINT SUPERSSN_Relationship FOREIGN KEY (SUPERSSN)
REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(SSN)
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
DNAME   Char(20)    NOT NULL,
DNUMBER Integer     NOT NULL,
MGR_SSN Integer     NOT NULL,
MGR_START_DATE  Date    NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (DNUMBER),
CONSTRAINT MGR_SSN_Relationship FOREIGN KEY(MGR_SSN)
REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(SSN)
);
```

Comment: ...also, SSNs should be char typed, not int.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the error you're getting is due to trying to reference the `DEPARTMENT` table before it exists?

If so, then the solution is simple.

- Create the `EMPLOYEE` table without the constraint that references the `DEPARTMENT` table;
- Create the `DEPARTMENT` table as above;
- Alter the `EMPLOYEE` table to add the constraint against the `DEPARTMENT` table.

Review the documentation on `ALTER TABLE` for how to use that command.

Given that there's no major changes needed once you know what the command is, here's a [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/80bb0) that shows you can create your tables if you pull the constraint against the then non-existent `DEPARTMENT` table out of `CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE`, and add that constraint in using `ALTER TABLE` once both tables exist. (Click the "Build Schema" button to see that it builds successfully).

---

As pointed out by @a1ex07, you will probably want to initially make `DEPARTMENT.MGR_SSN` and `EMPLOYEE.DNO` `NULL` instead of `NOT NULL`; in fact, at least one will need to be `NULL`.

The problem would be that, initially, you have no rows in either table. You would be unable to insert a row into `EMPLOYEE` because there would be no valid value you could provide for `DNO`, and you'd be unable to insert a row into `DEPARTMENT` because you could provide no valid value for `MGR_SSN`.

Keeping in mind our above solution, you could

- make `DEPARTMENT.MGR_SSN` allow NULL values initially
- create the departments you need (with no managers)
- add your employees (`EMPLOYEE.DNO` can be `NOT NULL`, as all the initial departments exist)
- update `DEPARTMENT` with the appropriate `MGR_SSN` values
- use `ALTER TABLE` to make `DEPARTMENT.MGR_SSN` `NOT NULL`.

Note, however, that you if you ever have a new department headed by a new employee, you'll need to:

- Create the new employee tied to an existing department;
- Create the new department, with the new employee as `MGR_SSN`;
- Update the employee with the correct `DNO`.